# Is it a good practice to invoke multiple rest calls in apache camel?

Tags: caching, routes, apache-camel, restlet

I have consider the following design for one the requirement

1. Camel Route listens(subscriber) to a jms(Topic) which has abstracted information.
2. Look up on the cache(Hazelcast) to get detail information  go to 5
3. On cache failure, Invoke REST endpoints (can be multiple in sequence)
4. Parse response of REST endpoints to get detailed information and add it to cache
5. Dynamically route to other jms endpoint based on detailed information

I'm not sure whether implementing the above solution is a good practice or not please advice me.